# Как избавиться от перезаписи файла?

Tags: java, groovy

Есть метод writeToFile, который записывает нужные данные в файл .txt, проблема в том что текст каждый раз перезаписывается, а мне нужно чтобы добавлялся.

```
public void writeToFile(def directory, def fileName, def extension, def infoList) {
      new File("$directory/$fileName$extension").withWriter { out ->
      infoList.each {
      out.println it      
    }
```

и вот код на котором испытываю метод

```
def directory = 'C:/Task_1'
def c
def txtFileInfo = []

    txtFileInfo << "Ваши данные - ${U_id}"
    txtFileInfo << "И ваши данные... - ${B_num}"
    writeToFile(directory, "info", ".txt", txtFileInfo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new File("$directory/$fileName$extension").withWriterAppend { ... }
```

Comment: я правильно понял?   `public void writeToFile(def directory, def fileName, def extension, def infoList) {
      new File("$directory/$fileName$extension").withWriterAppend {
      infoList.each {
      out.println it      
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Да, просто `withWriter` заменить на `withWriterAppend`.

Comment: у меня вылетает ошибка 'groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: out for class: 1'